# How do I find the location of all files with a particular name whose content contains a particular string?

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I want to find the location of all files named `index.php` that contain the string "hello".

thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `grep` with `find`:

```
find /top-dir -type f -name index.php -exec grep -l 'hello' {} +
```

where `/top-dir` is the path to the top-most directory that you want to search.

With `-type f`, we only look at regular files with `find`, and with `-name index.php` we restrict the search to files called `index.php`.

`-exec grep -l 'hello' {} +` will run `grep` on the found files and it will output the paths of all the files that matches the pattern (`'hello'`). It's the `-l` with `grep` that causes the output of the paths.

With `+` at the end, `find` will give as many files as possible to each invocation of `grep`. Changing this to `';'` or `\;` would result in `grep` being invoked with one file at a time, which may be slow if there are many files.

Comment: You could mention the `grep -l --null hello {} + | xargs -r0 cmd` as the safer (GNU or some BSDs) way to pass that list of files to a command (as that's apparently what the OP wants to do, from comments)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I never saw that comment, but do leave your comment here if it may help the OP. I'm going into a long meeting now...

Comment: (sorry, that wasn't a comment but a deleted answer)

Answer (score 3):

Use `grep` as following within a `find` command :

```
find -type f -name "index.php" -exec grep -q 'hello' '{}' \; -exec echo '{}' \;
```

Comment: That spawns 1 grep process per file and one echo process per matching file (and has issues with filenames containing backslashes if you have a Unix-compliant `echo`) so is a lot less efficient than [@Kusalananda's `grep -l` approach](/a/387694).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I cannot edit my answer to improve it as it will duplicate of other answers

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I have posted [my new another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387785/72456) which it will return the files if has backslash in there name

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the bash shell, enable the `globstar` option so `**` will match inside subdirectories, then just use `grep` like normal:

```
shopt -s globstar
grep -l hello **/index.php
```

(You only have to `shopt -s globstar` once in a shell, unless you disable the option with `shopt -u globstar`.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a GNU `grep` only approach which is returning relative path of matched files in current working directory and recursively and only files name is 'index.php'.

```
grep -rl --include="index.php" "hello" .
```

Here is also you can get absolute path for matched files replacing `.` with `${PWD}` instead:

```
grep -rl --include="index.php" "hello" "${PWD}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another 2 ways with `find` command:

```
find -type f -name "index.php" -exec grep -l 'hello' {} \;
```

---

```
find -type f -name "index.php" -exec grep -q 'hello' {} \; -print
```